# How to send automatic emails in aspnet core?

Tags: asp.net-core

**I would like to send automatic email notifications to users after 30 days of inactivity.**

For now i can send them manually (one by one), but this is time consuming.

**How can i do it automatically, in the background?**

Aspnet Core 6.0 C# + Bootstrap 5 + SQL Server

Comment: you need a time trigger? or some other webhocks? like a background service keep scanning your database and then make sure which user is inactive for 30 days then send email?

Answer (score 0):

In my humble opinion, you need a trigger to help query inactive users and sent email to them at times. And I used to use [Azure function time trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=in-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp) to do it. And here's my test for your scenario.

Firstly, I have to expose API which is used to query the inactive users, and another one is used to send email.

```
public string sendEmail(string emailAddress) {
    return "send to "+ emailAddress + " successfully";
}

public string queryInactive() { 
    return "user1@xx.com";
}
```

Then creating an Azure function time trigger to set it triggered every 9 am. Then write code to let the function call these 2 apis.

```
#r "Newtonsoft.Json"

using System;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public static void Run(TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx/home/queryInactive");
    request.Method = "GET";

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    Stream myResponseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(myResponseStream, Encoding.UTF8);
    String userAddress = reader.ReadToEnd();
    log.LogInformation(userAddress);

    HttpWebRequest request2 = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://xxxx/home/sendEmail?emailAddress="+userAddress);
    request.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse response2 = (HttpWebResponse)request2.GetResponse();
    Stream myResponseStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream();
    StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(myResponseStream2, Encoding.UTF8);
    String responseString = reader2.ReadToEnd();
    log.LogInformation(responseString);
}
```

And this is my test result.

[image]

Comment: I am using the Razor pages WEB app, not a RestFul APi and i am not using Azure. How can i implement this in a Razor web app?

Comment: I never did that and that's why I shared how I do with Azure. And if you want to do it by yourself, maybe [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio) can help.